# Java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists cursor in stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, cursor, sqlexception

Hello I have a method that calls a stored procedure, but I'm getting the next error:

"GRAVE [cl.auter.sictrav.daos.sictrav.ControladorDao] (MSC service thread 1-1) java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists
: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists"

referring to this line ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cStmt.getObject(3);

My code is

```
    public List obtenerBitsEstadoDao(Controlador controlador) {
    DBSictrav conn = new DBSictrav();
    List bitsestado = new ArrayList();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = conn.getConection("");
        String query = "{ call pkg_plan_sic.pg_obt_bit_est_crc_ctl(?,?,?,?,?)}";
        try (CallableStatement cStmt = connection.prepareCall(query)) {
            cStmt.setString(1, "CT");
            cStmt.setInt(2, controlador.getId());
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cStmt.executeQuery();
            if (cStmt.getInt(4) == 0) {
                try
                { 
                    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cStmt.getObject(3);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        BitEstado bc = new BitEstado(rs.getString("BIT_CRUCE"));
                        bc.setFaseReal(rs.getString("BIT_CONTROLADOR"));
                        bc.setPosicion(rs.getInt("POSICION"));
                        bc.setControlador(controlador);
                        bitsestado.add(bc);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new SictravDaoException((String) cStmt.getObject(5), cStmt.getInt(4));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
    } finally {

        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlanDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return bitsestado;
}
```

The Stored Procedure

```
procedure pg_obt_bit_crc_ctl(
                       p_tipo      in  varchar2,
                       p_id        in  number,
                       p_cur_lis   out cur_ref,
                       p_cod_err   out number,
                       p_des_err   out varchar2) is


 --
  v_string   varchar2(32000);
  v_ind_whe  boolean := false;
  v_num_lin  varchar2(10);
  --
  cursor bit_por_cr is
    select distinct c.id_cruce,
           t.id_masccontrol,
           16 - instr(dec2bin(bit00), '1') + 1 F1
           c.codigo codigo
      from tbl_mascara_control m,
           tbl_controlador     t,
           tbl_cruce           c
     where m.id_masccontrol = t.id_masccontrol
       and c.id_controlador = t.id_controlador
            and c.id_cruce = p_id;
  --
  cursor bit_por_ct is
         select t.id_controlador id_cruce,
             t.id_masccontrol,
           16 - instr(dec2bin(bit00), '1') + 1 F1,
           16-instr(dec2bin(bit08),'1')+1 RR
           //more similar lines 
        from tbl_mascara_control m,
             tbl_controlador t
       where m.id_masccontrol = t.id_masccontrol
         and t.id_controlador =  p_id;
  --
  v_fase_ini       number;
  v_num_ctl        number;
  v_num_fase       number;
  v_ind_fase_check number;
  posIni           number;
  posFin           number;
  v_idx_pal        number;
  v_cnt            number;
  v_num_paralelo   number;
  --
  begin
    -->Borramos los datos de la tabla temporal orientada a la transaccion...
    commit;
--

if p_tipo = 'CT' then
    --
    for c in bit_por_ct loop

        if (c.f1 is not null) then
          insert into tbl_tmp_bits_cruce(id_cruce, bit_cruce, bit_controlador, posicion) values(c.id_cruce, 'F1', 'F1',  c.F1);
        end if;
        //More similar lines ...

        if (c.PR1 is not null) then
          insert into tbl_tmp_bits_cruce(id_cruce, bit_cruce, bit_controlador, posicion) values(c.id_cruce, 'PR1', 'PR1',  c.PR1);
        end if;

        if (c.PR2 is not null) then
          insert into tbl_tmp_bits_cruce(id_cruce, bit_cruce, bit_controlador, posicion) values(c.id_cruce, 'PR2', 'PR2',  c.PR2);
        end if;

        if (c.PR3 is not null) then
          insert into tbl_tmp_bits_cruce(id_cruce, bit_cruce, bit_controlador, posicion) values(c.id_cruce, 'PR3', 'PR3',  c.PR3);
        end if;

        if (c.PR4 is not null) then
          insert into tbl_tmp_bits_cruce(id_cruce, bit_cruce, bit_controlador, posicion) values(c.id_cruce, 'PR4', 'PR4',  c.PR4);
        end if;

        --
        if (c.RR is not null) then
          insert into tbl_tmp_bits_cruce(id_cruce, bit_cruce, bit_controlador, posicion) values(c.id_cruce, 'RR', 'RR',  c.RR);
        end if;
        --
        // More similar ifs
        --
    end loop;
end if;
--
open p_cur_lis for
     select b.id_cruce, b.bit_cruce, b.bit_controlador, b.posicion,c.codigo
     from tbl_tmp_bits_cruce b,tbl_cruce c
     where b.id_cruce=c.id_cruce(+)
     order by b.posicion ;
--
--> ahora recorremos el cursor...
v_num_lin := '60';
p_cod_err := 0;
p_des_err := '';
--
exception
  when others then
      p_cod_err := -20000;
      p_des_err := 'Error al obtener Bits por cruce o controlador';
end pg_obt_bit_crc_ctl;
```

I'm getting this error and I dont know why or how to fix it. I tried with ojdbc6 and ojdbc14 same result.
some suggestion?

Comment: Does it help if you turn off autoCommit on the connection  (`connection.setAutoCommit(false)`) prior to executing the call?

Comment: It worked as a charm. But if I remember correctly I tried it before and I got a transaction error somewhere.

Comment: If you disable autoCommit, then you must also remember to manually commit or rollback the transaction when you're done.  It's probably also a good idea to restore the original `autoCommit` state -- whatever that was; see `Connection.getAutoCommit()` -- before allowing the reference to your connection to escape.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you post your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the cursor returned by your stored procedure is valid only within the same transaction in which the SP itself runs.  If your connection is operating in autocommit mode then that transaction ends before the `executeQuery()` method returns.  Out parameters of other types survive the end of the transaction, but the cursor ceases to be valid.

You can address this problem by taking manual control of the transaction boundaries.  To do so, you must ensure that the connection is not in autocommit mode, *and* you must be certain to manually commit the transaction or roll it back before your method returns.  Here's an outline:

```
try {
    Connection connection = conn.getConnection();

    try {
        CallableStatement cStmt;

        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        cStmt = connection.prepareCall(query);
        // ... register parameters ...

        try {
            cStmt.executeQuery();

            // ... extract and process SP out parameters ...

            connection.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connection.rollback();
            // ... other handling ...
        }
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle it ...
}
```

Also, programming in full defensive mode would call for restoring the original connection autocommit state before returning, so as to avoid interfering with other uses of the underlying `Connection` managed by your datasource.  I have not modeled that above because the datasource should not require it, but this would be a defense against a plausible current or future bug in the DS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consider two things when working with CURSOR in mybatis and spring

1. The declaration should be in one line . Break only when parameters are present

{ call my_proc(#{paramName,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},#{out, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR,resultMap=franApplicationSettings})}

2. If you get this error

   ORA-08103: object no longer exists cursor in stored procedure

   You have to ensure that the spring method is annotated with @Transactional
       The reason is cursor reference is lost after mybatis gives it to oracle.